# Count total occurrences in subarray with Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, count, smarty

I have this array:

```
[attributes] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id_attribute] => 1
                        [id_attribute_group] => 1
                        [name] => Rosso
                        [group] => Colore
                        [reference] => WD1012
                        [ean13] => 
                        [isbn] => 
                        [upc] => 
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [id_attribute] => 24236
                        [id_attribute_group] => 9
                        [name] => 31 x 86.5 cm.
                        [group] => Dimensioni Fiore 1
                        [reference] => WD1012
                        [ean13] => 
                        [isbn] => 
                        [upc] => 
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [id_attribute] => 24237
                        [id_attribute_group] => 10
                        [name] => 31 x 71.5 cm.
                        [group] => Dimensioni Fiore 2
                        [reference] => WD1012
                        [ean13] => 
                        [isbn] => 
                        [upc] => 
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [id_attribute] => 24238
                        [id_attribute_group] => 11
                        [name] => 32.5 x 88 cm.
                        [group] => Dimensioni Fiore 3
                        [reference] => WD1012
                        [ean13] => 
                        [isbn] => 
                        [upc] => 
                    )

            )
```

I want to count the [group] value while searching its value a word:

```
{foreach from=$variants item=variant}
    {if $variant.group|stristr:'Dimensioni'}
        {$variant.group} 
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Output:

```
Dimensioni Fiore 1
Dimensioni Fiore 2
Dimensioni Fiore 3
```

Now I want to count the total occurrences inside arrays (should be 3):

```
{$variant.group|count}
```

output:

```
1
1
1
```

I have to count the occurrences as if they are 2 or more, it must does something, but the output count only 1 occurrence for each array and not the total.
What's the way to achieving this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`counter`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.counter) to do this:

```
{counter print=false start=0 name=Dimensioni assign=dimensioniCount}
{foreach from=$variants item=variant}
    {if $variant.group|stristr:'Dimensioni'}
        {$variant.group}
        {counter name=Dimensioni}
    {/if}
{/foreach}

{if $dimensioniCount>=2}
    <h1>Do something here</h1>
{/if}
```